# Apprise Alert Flashes and Goes Away

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to get the "Apprise" alert [plugin](http://thrivingkings.com/read/Apprise-The-attractive-alert-alternative-for-jQuery) to work on my website.  I have all of the necessary files, so that isn't the problem.

What happens is that when I click on a 'Submit' button, I can see the alert on the screen for a split second before it just disappears.
When I use the regular `alert()`, and not `apprise()`, the alert stays there and there are no problems.

It seems to be a problem whenever I use the `<a>` tag, because I can use the "li" tag with `apprise()` and it works perfectly.  Do you know why it would flash and then go away right away?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How about some code or potentially a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

> *"It seems to be a problem whenever I use the "a" tag, because I can use the "li" tag with "apprise()" and it works perfectly. Do you know why it would flash and then go away right away?"*

The default behaviour for the anchor tag is probably what's messing this up for you - normally when you click an anchor some kind of navigation takes place, whether within the current page or to another page. You can cancel the default anchor click behaviour from within your click event handler.

You didn't show any of your html or JS code, so I can only guess at your code structure, but assuming you're using `.apprise()` from within a click handler on an `<a>` tag try cancelling the default behaviour:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
   // your code here
   // something.apprise(); etc

   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is very helpful!  It works with the a tag, but I am actually using it with a submit button.  I tried to mimick your directions, but it doesn't do anything except redirect.  It doesn't even flash when I put this code in the .js validation file. I think I am pretty close though!  Thanks again!  Here is my code below:
`function overall (data) {
   valid = true;
   FirstName()
   State()
   Email()
   Message()
   if (valid==true){
   $("button").click(function(e) {
apprise('test');  
   e.preventDefault();
}); 
 }
 else {
}
 return valid;
}`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but I've just had exactly the same problem and was able fix it like this:

```
apprise('test', null, function(){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

So now the execution will wait until the apprise 'OK' button is clicked, then the preventDefault() cancels the button's default behaviour.